# Removing extra dotted lines in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have drawn the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images

\title{feynds}
\author{ts342139 }
\date{October 2023}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\usepackage{contour}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\tikzfeynmanset{plain/.style=}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{slashed}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
%\fancyhead{LE}
\fancyhead[RO]{\nouppercase{\leftmark\hfill}}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\hfill\thepage\hfill}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
    % Define the coordinates

        \foreach \x in {0}
        \foreach \y in {1,2,3,4}
            \foreach \z in {0,1,2,3,4}
            {
                \draw (\x,\y,\z) circle (0.1cm);
                \fill[green] (\x,\y,\z) circle (0.05cm);
            }
        \foreach \x in {0}
        \foreach \y in {0}
            \foreach \z in {1,2,3,4}
            {
                \draw (\x,\y,\z) circle (0.1cm);
                \fill[green] (\x,\y,\z) circle (0.05cm);
            }
        \foreach \x in {1,2,3,4}
        \foreach \y in {0,1,2,3,4}
            \foreach \z in {0,1,2,3,4}
            {
                \draw (\x,\y,\z) circle (0.1cm);
                \fill[green] (\x,\y,\z) circle (0.05cm);
            }

    % Connect the circles with dotted lines
    \foreach \x in {0,1,2,3,4}
        \foreach \y in {0,1,2,3,4}
            \foreach \z in {0,1,2,3,4}
            {
                \draw[dotted] (\x,\y,\z) -- (\x+1,\y,\z);
                \draw[dotted] (\x,\y,\z) -- (\x,\y+1,\z);
                \draw[dotted] (\x,\y,\z) -- (\x,\y,\z+1);
            }

    % Draw the axes
    \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (4.5,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$\nu_1$};
    \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,4.5,0) node[anchor=north west]{$\nu_2$};
    \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,4.5) node[anchor=south]{$\nu_3$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

but there are some extra dotted lines after the last circle ends.
[image]

how to remove them?

Comment: Without having compiled I suspect you should end your loops at 3, not 4 …

Comment: if I stop at 3 then it does not look good, no connection will be there at the end except from one side. I want a complete lattice structure

Comment: What dotted lines and circles are you talking about?

Comment: Please post only the code needed for your question. We really don't need your headers or to know you're using `wrapfig`, `contour` and the rest of it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you want connections to the `4`s, you don't want connections to the `5`s. So either remove `4` from the loops and handle those cases separately or avoid drawing to `5`s within the loop. I take the second approach here.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
  % define coords
  \foreach \x in {0}
  \foreach \y in {1,2,3,4}
  \foreach \z in {0,1,2,3,4}
  {
    \draw (\x,\y,\z) circle (0.1cm);
    \fill[green] (\x,\y,\z) circle (0.05cm);
  }
  \foreach \x in {0}
  \foreach \y in {0}
  \foreach \z in {1,2,3,4}
  {
    \draw (\x,\y,\z) circle (0.1cm);
    \fill[green] (\x,\y,\z) circle (0.05cm);
  }
  \foreach \x in {1,2,3,4}
  \foreach \y in {0,1,2,3,4}
  \foreach \z in {0,1,2,3,4}
  {
    \draw (\x,\y,\z) circle (0.1cm);
    \fill[green] (\x,\y,\z) circle (0.05cm);
  }
  
  % Connect the circles with dotted lines
  \foreach \x in {0,1,2,3,4}
  \foreach \y in {0,1,2,3,4}
  \foreach \z in {0,1,2,3,4}
  {
    \ifnum\x<4
      \draw[dotted] (\x,\y,\z) -- (\x+1,\y,\z);
    \fi
    \ifnum\y<4
      \draw[dotted] (\x,\y,\z) -- (\x,\y+1,\z);
    \fi
    \ifnum\z<4
      \draw[dotted] (\x,\y,\z) -- (\x,\y,\z+1);
    \fi
  }
  
  % Draw the axes
  \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (4.5,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$\nu_1$};
  \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,4.5,0) node[anchor=north west]{$\nu_2$};
  \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,4.5) node[anchor=south]{$\nu_3$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Apologies for being unable to post an image. KDE/Okular currently has an extremely aggravating bug which renders such images ugly, at best, and useless, at worst. The chance of such an image showing your dotted lines at all is as close to zero as makes no odds.